# Attempt to call a Instance value

Tags: lua, roblox

This error keeps popping up in output, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
function bullet() --function giving me errors
    bullet = Instance.new("Part") --instance
    bullet.Size = Vector3.new(1,1,1)
    bullet.Position = script.Parent.Position
    bullet.Parent = workspace
    bullet.Velocity = script.Parent.CFrame.LookVector * 90
    bullet.CanCollide = false
    --dont think making the script disable then enable after a certain time will work
end

script.Parent.Parent.Activated:Connect(function() --the script is in the handle of the tool
    bullet() -- where the error is
    --weird thing is, i have made functions like "explode()" that worked just like this and did not have any errors
    --pretty sure this is a roblox problem, but i am not sure
    --someone help
end)
```

the error: "Workspace.Tool.Handle.Script:12: attempt to call a Instance value"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> --pretty sure this is a roblox problem, but i am not sure

Not the cause is your code.

You define a global function named `bullet`

```
function bullet()
-- more code
end
```

The first thing you do in that function is

```
bullet = Instance.new("Part")
```

Doing that you assign the return value of `Instance.new("Part")` to `bullet`.

Let's call function `bullet` the first time `bullet()`

Now the function is executed and `bullet` becomes an Instance. It is not a function anymore.

If we now call `bullet` a second time we get the error

> "Workspace.Tool.Handle.Script:12: attempt to call a Instance value"

So `bullet` basically overwrites itself so it can not be called a second time.

Just use different names to avoid this. Then you should think about the scope. If you want to create a new bullet every time you call `bullet` you need to make the Intance value local as you would otherwise overwrite the same global bullet every time you call the function.

Try something like

```
function SpawnBullet() --function giving me errors
    local bullet = Instance.new("Part") --instance
    bullet.Size = Vector3.new(1,1,1)
    bullet.Position = script.Parent.Position
    bullet.Parent = workspace
    bullet.Velocity = script.Parent.CFrame.LookVector * 90
    bullet.CanCollide = false
    return bullet
end

script.Parent.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    SpawnBullet()
end)
```

Comment: ohhhhh
yeah sorry, forgot about that lol

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the bullet variable inside the bullet function something besides `bullet` or change the name of the function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the name of the function or the variable? Maybe that's the problem.

Try:

```
function CreateBullet() --function giving me errors
    bullet = Instance.new("Part") --instance
    bullet.Size = Vector3.new(1,1,1)
    bullet.Position = script.Parent.Position
    bullet.Parent = workspace
    bullet.Velocity = script.Parent.CFrame.LookVector * 90
    bullet.CanCollide = false
end

script.Parent.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    CreateBullet()
end)
```

I'm sorry if it didn't work or if I wasn't helpful.

Comment: what happens if you call the function is called a second time? do you think it will behave "as expected", which to me means I have 2 bullets in the air.